# Is Entity Framework truly async at all levels including the driver?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asynchronous

When using async in ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework, I'm curious if the entire stack is truly asynchronous or not.

i.e. if an async action calls `.SaveChangesAsync`, is the SQL Server driver async or will it just block and run in its own thread pool?

Comment: EF relies on ADO.NET which supports async. The Async calls in EF just get passed through to those. I am not sure if I understand you about the Sql driver. Mabye you are not 100% what the async/await pattern entails, see [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)?

Comment: It is open source so you can dig.

Answer (score 0):

The driver isn't part of EF, and there isn't "the driver" as EF can work with several.

EF is async all the way through to ADO.NET.

ADO.NET provides asynchronous operations in a backwards compatible way so that if you used an old driver with it it would run the operation synchronously, but providers can override this with true async operations.

The SQLServer provider in ADO.NET, which is the most likely provider to use with SQLServer uses async I/O. So do many (most?) of the other providers.